# jQuery-UI slider is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I tried a lot of solutions that i found in other questions but none of them solve my problem, i really don't know why my code is not working, there's no errors in console and the jquery and jquery-ui are the latest versions.

**References**

```
    <script src="jQuery3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="jQueryUI1.12.1-darkness.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
    crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Slider**

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: parseInt(0),
        max: parseInt(1440),
        step: parseInt(15),
        value: parseInt(600),
        slide: function(e, ui) {
          var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
          var minutes1 = ui.values[0] - (hours1 * 60);

          if (hours1.length == 1) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
          if (minutes1.length == 1) minutes1 = '0' + minutes1;
          if (minutes1 == 0) minutes1 = '00';
          if (hours1 >= 12) {
            if (hours1 == 12) {
              hours1 = hours1;
              minutes1 = minutes1 + " PM";
            } else {
              hours1 = hours1 - 12;
              minutes1 = minutes1 + " PM";
                        }
                    } else {
                        hours1 = hours1;
                        minutes1 = minutes1 + " AM";
                    }
                    if (hours1 == 0) {
                        hours1 = 12;
                        minutes1 = minutes1;
                    }



                    $('.slider-time').html(hours1 + ':' + minutes1);
                }
            });
```

**CSS**

```
            #time-range p {
                font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #333;
            }
            #slider-range {
                width: 80%;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
        <div id="time-range">
            <p>Time Range: <span class="slider-time">10:00 AM</span> - <span class="slider-time2">12:00 PM</span>

            </p>
            <div class="sliders_step1">
                <div id="slider-range"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I really need to fix this fast as posssible!

The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bruno_mond/bwg6rpfx/8/) here.

Comment: What is the behavior you're seeing? Can you isolate what IS working from what is NOT working? For example, get rid of all your logic and just try to create an out of the box slider. Does that work? Baby steps..

Comment: I also don't understand why you're calling `parseInt` and passing in a `number`. That doesn't make sense

Comment: i tried to create a single box slider and still not showing, the screen shows only the text.

Comment: in another question with the same problem a guy used the parseInt and said it worked

Comment: `parseInt` is for parsing an integer. Your value is already an integer. `parseInt` does nothing here.

Comment: Try making a JSFiddle that reproduced your problem. From looking at your code, the problem isn't easily spotted. If you create a jsfiddle of your problem you'll get help a lot quicker since you are providing everyone with a (non)working example of your problem.

Comment: I add the JSFiddle in the question, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this code.

```js
$(function() {
  function formatTime(h, m, f) {
    if (f == undefined) {
      f = true;
    }
    var time;
    if (f) {
      var fh = (h > 12 ? h - 12 : h);
      if (h == 24) {
        fh = 12
      } else if (fh == 0) {
        fh = 12;
      }
      time = "" + (fh < 10 ? "0" + fh : fh) + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" + m : m) + (h > 11 && h != 24 ? " PM" : " AM");
    } else {
      time = "" + (h < 10 ? "0" + h : h) + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" + m : m);
    }
    return time;
  }
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 24,
    step: .25,
    values: [10, 12],
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      var times = [{
        hour: Math.floor(ui.values[0])
      }, {
        hour: Math.floor(ui.values[1])
      }];
      times[0].min = (ui.values[0] - times[0].hour) * 60;
      times[1].min = (ui.values[1] - times[1].hour) * 60;

      $('.slider-time').html(formatTime(times[0].hour, times[0].min));
      $('.slider-time2').html(formatTime(times[1].hour, times[1].min));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#time-range p {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}

#slider-range {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="time-range">
  <p>Time Range: <span class="slider-time">10:00 AM</span> - <span class="slider-time2">12:00 PM</span>

  </p>
  <div class="sliders_step1">
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Trying to range between 0 and 2400 is difficult since we're working with cause we're not working with 10, but 60. For example, time is counted like 1400, 1415, 1430, 1445, 1500 but the slider will count like 1400, 1415, 1430, 1445, 1460, 1475, 1490, 1505. So as the slider moves, you're going to get none time values.

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| x    | h = flour(x / 60) | m = x - (h * 60) |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 600  | 10                | 0                |
| 1215 | 20                | 15               |
| 1360 | 22                | 40               |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

You can see how this begins to breakdown. Now if you switch percentages of an hour, .25 or 25% of 60 minutes becomes 15 minutes.

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| x     | h = floor(x) | m = (x - h) * 60 |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 6.00  | 6            | 0                |
| 12.25 | 12           | 15               |
| 13.75 | 13           | 45               |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Then you want to format your Hour and Minutes to either a 12 hour format: `hh:mm A/PM` or a 24 hour format `hh:mm`. This is pretty easy to do so I moved it to a function of it's own so that you can easily adjust.

Hope this helps.